# Generating scaffold in Visual Studio ignores Layout

Tags: visual-studio, razor, razor-pages, visual-studio-mac

I'm going through the RazorPages tutorial by Microsoft, after creating a Model I go on to set up a scaffold. In the settings I want to use the current layout that's found in `_viewstart`, the settings tell me to leave it blank if I want to use that layout file:
[image: Text]

However, when I continue with these settings, my view pages are created with `null` as a layout:

`/Movies/Index.cshtml`:

```
@page
@model RazorPagesMovie.Pages.Movies.IndexModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Is this a bug? Should I have to manually specify the layout page in the settings?

Comment: Leave the **Use a layout page** option unchecked if your layout page is specified in __ViewStart_.

Comment: After switching from ef 2 to ef 3 we noticed the same problem (we've switched it just a few days ago because oracle ef 3 had been delayed a lot...). Scaffold now generates Layout = null; even when "Use a layout page" is unchecked. It's a bug, imho.